# Coding Challenge String Methods Python

Tags: python, string, methods

**Code:**

```
# function receives user input
def ask_sentence():
    # .replace() function takes two parameters (old string, new string replacement)
    sentence1 = input("Enter sentence 1: ").lower().replace(" ","") 
    sentence2 = input("Enter sentence 2: ").lower().replace(" ","") 

ask_sentence()
```

**Help:**

I am trying to create a program that takes two sentences as input from the user and then outputs the letters that occur in both sentences only once

**For example:**

sentence1 = 'I like cheese'

sentence2 = 'I need shoes'

output = iesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this the `set` would be perfect I think:

```
# function receives user input
def ask_sentence():
    # .replace() function takes two parameters (old string, new string replacement)
    sentence1 = set(input("Enter sentence 1: ").lower().replace(" ",""))
    sentence2 = set(input("Enter sentence 2: ").lower().replace(" ",""))

    print(sentence1)
    print(sentence2)
```

ask_sentence()

Comment: Then wouldn't you need to do `sentence1 & sentence2` to get the letters that appear in both?